# Scraping a table of data from a pop up dialog using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to scrape flight prices over a range of dates from google flights. I have done the following (with some help from stackoverflow) and opened up the pop up with the grid of flight prices over a range of dates.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/travel/flights')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-placeholder='Where from?'] input"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Enter your origin'] input"))).send_keys("Sydney" + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ENTER)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-placeholder='Where to?'] input"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Enter your destination'] input"))).send_keys("Auckland" + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ENTER)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Search']"))).click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

print(driver.current_url)

# opening up date grid
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Date grid']"))).click()
```

I am now unsure how I can refer to the open pop up and scrape the values from the table there since it isn't its own webpage and doesn't have its own URL

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure how many pop-ups are there, you can try something like this. I used something similar with my scraping projects.

```
main_window_handle = browser.current_window_handle
for window_handle in browser.window_handles:
    if window_handle != main_window_handle:
        browser.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break
```

You can use `browser.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)` after finishing your work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34185122)

Comment: I had 46 reputation then and I wasn't able to comment that why I wrote "(I am not able to comment so I post my suggestion as answer, my apologies)" before it got deleted/edited. This was just a suggestion, not an answer

Comment: That does not excuse using an answer when it should have been a comment. If anything, posting a comment as an answer is circumventing the rep-limit. Now that you have the privilege, you should post suggestions as comments in the future.

Comment: I just tried to help someone and that's why I posted it as an answer but I indicated it's not 'the' answer

Comment: And of course I'll use comments if I need to comment or suggest something, I would have done it in the first place if I could, or avoid posting it as answer if someone helped the op